# DateTime.ParseExact C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Не получается распарсить дату.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.ParseExact("11 марта 15:32", "dd MM HH:mm", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"));
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Вызвано исключение:

> System.FormatException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В описании формата даты `MM`  это месяц в диапазоне от `01` до `12`.
Если используется полное название месяца, как здесь

> 11 марта 15:32

Необходимо использовать `MMMM`.

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact("11 марта 15:32", "dd MMMM HH:mm", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

Более подробно об описании формата даты можно прочитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

> MM

А должно быть `ММММ` и то я не уверен, ждёт он `март` или `марта`.

Да, всё распарсилось: http://ideone.com/P1B7x2.